# Find a function f : B → C such that h = f ∘ g

Tags: relations

Find a function $f : B → C$ such that $h = f ∘ g$, or prove that such function do not exist

A={1,2,3}, B={4,5,6}, C={7,8,9}

$g : A → B$
 $h : A → C $
 $f : B → C$

$g(1)=5, g(2)=5, g(3)=6, h(1)=7, h(2)=8, h(3)=9$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $h$ is bijective, but $g$ is not. In fact $|\text{im}(g)|=2$. How many elements are there maximally  in $\text{im}(f\circ g)$?

Comment: any more hints please? i dont really undarstand why $|{im}(g)|=2$

Comment: $\text{im}(g)=\left\{y\in B\mid \exists x\in A: g(x)=y\right\}=\left\{5,6\right\}$.